# Dry lined walls crumbling when trying to put a nail into the wall

Tags: walls, plaster, nails

Whenever I paint my walls the paint underneath peels off--like wallpaper, but it was only paint. I’ve now tried to attach things to the walls and then I do the wall crumbles away down to the brick. I figure this is because my walls are dry lined.

I’m trying to nail a few things into the walls but the nails are constantly getting bent before they can even hit the brick because the plaster wall onto just peels away.

How can I prevent this and be able to put a nail into the wall? Thanks.

Comment: try drilling pilot holes for the nails. Pilot hole is smaller then the nail

Comment: A picture of the wall in general, then a close up of an area with peeling paint and where it's crumbled from attempting to drive a nail would probably be helpful. However, if you're trying to drive a nail into brick, that's just not going to work well. Bricks don't like nails.